# Setting psql border style with -c option

Tags: postgresql, psql, postgresql-9.4

I want to save several postgresql function definitions to a file. I have a working script, but the border style seems to default to "1", and I'd like to have the border be "2". I've tried passing an extra `-c '\pset border 2'` but, that doesn't seem to have any affect. From the documentation, I know what any `.psqlrc` file is ignored when passing the `-c` arg, but it seems like there should be a way to control your preferences for outputs.

How to control the border and any other `\pset` options (such as `null`) when using `-c`?

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-c` is only for SQL queries, not for meta-commands.

Use `-P` or `--pset` for the command-line version of `\pset`.

Example:

```
psql -P linestyle=unicode -P border=2 -c "select 1 as col"
```

Result:

```
┌─────┐
│ col │
├─────┤
│   1 │
└─────┘
(1 row)
```